# Disable Visual Studio 2015 comment alignment?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, comments, indentation, text-editor

In Visual Studio 2015, if you have code like this:

```
var foo = that.Bar(); // Get the value
//foo++;
```

selecting Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document results in formatting like this:

```
var foo = that.Bar(); // Get the value
                      //foo++;
```

where Visual Studio has assumed two unrelated comments were related and grouped them together.  The assumption of relation is because there are consecutive lines, one ending with a comment and the next starting with one.  This can, of course, be worked around by adding blank lines but that is not always the best choice depending on the specific code.  Note that Visual Studio 2013 did not have this feature.

I was unable to find any mention of this feature via internet searches.  This is C#, and Visual Studio is configured to preserve tabs.

Is there any way to disable this one portion of the auto-formatting?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45774439/visual-studio-2015-how-to-preserve-indentation-of-comments  this thread discusses where the option is for c++ (probably, I didn't check it), but there is no corresponding option for c#. I think this problem started with some vs2015 update, because I feel this nuisance is a relatively new one.

Comment: This behavior is a huge nuisance, since:
1. It groups possibly unrelated comments
2. It causes large number of changes that show up when diffing files
3. In C# there is no way to turn it off even though it can evidently be done since C++ has this option

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible. I've found [this post on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/8224) where one comment mentioned your problem. CyrusNajmabadi wrote:

> Interestingly enough, we added some support to align comments over multiple lines. So, for example, in the example being mentioned, post format you end up with:
>
> [image: Comment alignment]
>
> Alignment is an interesting problem, and currently we have no support for alignment to happen with tabs when formatting between tokens. However, it gets more and more complex considering you might have these comments attached to items which themselves get moved around by formatting and thus may have their locations move to places that are not on tabstop boundaries.

Comment: Thanks diiN__________.  That issue on GitHub seems to actually be about preservation of mid-line tabs (or lack of preservation) on lines with comments, but it gives me a good place to look around.  The case I'm encountering is about insertion of extra indenting tabs at the start of the line.I'm guessing you are right that it isn't possible.  I even searched the registry.  But wanted to hope for someone knowing a secret setting.  :-)

Comment: CyrusNajmabadi repeatedly says that the real problem is that fixing this would require a huge proliferation of rules. However it makes more sense to say that if there is not a specific rule in place to just leave the code alone! If MS wants to indent consecutive comments to match each other, that should be an option, not the default behavior.

Comment: Has anything changed since then?