# Visual Studio 2015 - How to Preserve Indentation of Comments?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ide, comments, indentation

Simple question. No answer given anywhere on the internet?

I program in C++ / C# in VS2015 community. When i comment out code and then close the ide and reopen it, this commented code loses indentation. How do i force VS to preserve indentation? It shouldn't be doing anything to the code / text that is commented. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS 2017 (C++) there is a checkbox for this.

Tools | Options | Text  Editor | C/C++ | Formatting | Indentation | Preserve indentation of comments

Unchecking it fixed annoying comment auto-formatting. Maybe the same option exists in VS 2015.